# Configure a complete costume protocol as IE Trusted Sites

Tags: windows, protocol, protocol-handler

I created a costume protocol (for a namespace extension application), structered: protocol:\path\to\file.

I'm trying to add the pathes in this protocol to Internet Option's Trusted Sites (to disable a widows warning popping every time i use the protocol), but windows doesn't let me add "protocol:*\" as a trusted site.

Any ideas? tell me if more details in needed